# Cannot invoke "com.mycompany.tablahash.Entrada.setKey(Object)" because "this.table[...]" is null

Tags: java

i have this code

```
if (table[(position + i * i) % capacidad] == null) {
                    table[(position + i * i) % capacidad].setKey(clave);
                    table[(position + i * i) % capacidad].setValue(valor);
                    check = true;
                }
```

And have this output about lane 2.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.mycompany.tablahash.Entrada.setKey(Object)" because "this.table[...]" is null
    at com.mycompany.tablahash.TablaHash.put(TablaHash.java:49)
    at com.mycompany.tablahash.ClienteTablaHash.main(ClienteTablaHash.java:19)
```

I checked with the debug and the dir((position + i * i) % capacidad) is 0.
This is the constructor

```
protected Entrada[] table;
    public TablaHash(int capacidad, boolean metodo) {
        this.capacidad = capacidad;
        this.metodoDeColisiones = metodo;
        this.table= new Entrada [capacidad];
    }
```

Capacity is settled at 100

Comment: The `table` variable is not null, but the `table[i]` variable, for some key value(s) of `i`, *is* null.  We only see you creating the array object, but nowhere do we see you filling it: Where is the code where you fill your table array with Entrada objects?

Comment: Ohhh i think that´s the problem, i dont initialize the table array.

Comment: Then that would explain everything